# VBA - Find duplicates and merge second column

Tags: vba, excel

I want a script to merge the first column as the key and with the second column combine the duplicates if unique..

E. G

```
Home | 1, 2, 3
Home | 1,2,3,4
Home | 1,2,3,4,5
Rome | 1, 2, 3
Rome | 1, 2
```

Will be

```
Home | 1,2,3,4,5
Rome | 1,2,3
```

How do I achieve this?

**Attempted code:**

```
    Sub test()
Dim teststring As String
Dim tarray As Variant
Dim separating As String

separating = ","
teststring = ""
rownum = 2

For i = 1 To 5

If teststring <> ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
teststring = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
rownum = i
Else
tarray = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value, separating)


For k = 1 To UBound(tarray)

If InStr(1, ActiveSheet.Cells(rownum, 2).Value, tarray(k)) = 0 Then
ActiveSheet.Cells(rownum, 2).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(rownum, 2).Value & separating & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value
End If

Next k

End If


Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Many ways. What have you tried? Post any code.

Comment: @SJR Please see edited code.

Comment: OK, scripting dictionaries is one way to go. I don't have time to post code right now, but will come back to if nobody else has answered in the meantime (which is unlikely).

Comment: @SJR  I don't think that its **that** unlikely based on the history of the OP. Apparently, he / she barely ever accepts an answer and up-votes are equally scarce. So, I (personally) don't feel compelled to post an answer.

Comment: @Ralph thanks for the comments Ralph.. If you look a tiny bit further you'll find that out of my very limited activity on this site, I have accepted answers where someone has given an answer that actually answers my question.. In most ones where I haven't it's because I either answered my own question or there was no answer. I have worked out the answer now and will be posting it when I'm back at my pc, thank you sjr for actually helping rather than trying to belittle me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code will merge the rows, sort them in ascending order and delete the duplicates (if there are no spaces in the input). Also duplicates dont have to be below each other like in your example. Try it out and let me know if it works for you.

```
Sub Merge()
Dim arr1() As String
Dim arr2() As String
Dim Separator As String
Dim i, s As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
s = 1
Separator = ","

For i = s + 1 To lastRow
    If ActiveSheet.Cells(s, 1).Value <> "" And ActiveSheet.Cells(s, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value And s <> i Then
        arr1 = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(s, 2).Value, Separator)
        arr2 = Split(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value, Separator)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(s, 2).Value = Output(arr1(), arr2())
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 2)).ClearContents
        lastRow = Worksheets("Tabelle1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    End If
    If i = lastRow Then
        If s = lastRow Then
            Exit For
        End If
        s = s + 1
        i = 0
    End If
Next i
End Sub


Function Output(arr1() As String, arr2() As String) As String
Dim x, y, z, Size1, Size2 As Integer
Dim strOutput As String
Dim arr3() As String

Size1 = UBound(arr1())
Size2 = UBound(arr2())

For x = 0 To Size1
    For y = 0 To Size2
        If arr1(x) = arr2(y) Then
            arr2(y) = "0"
        End If
    Next y
Next x

arr3 = Split(Join(arr1, ",") & "," & Join(arr2, ","), ",")
arr3 = BubbleSort(arr3)

For z = 0 To UBound(arr3())
    If arr3(z) <> "0" Then
        strOutput = strOutput & "," & arr3(z)
    End If
Next z

Output = Right(strOutput, Len(strOutput) - 1)
End Function

Function BubbleSort(ByRef strArray() As String) As String()
   Dim z       As Long
   Dim i       As Long
   Dim strWert As Variant

    For z = UBound(strArray) - 1 To LBound(strArray) Step -1
        For i = LBound(strArray) To z
            If LCase(strArray(i)) > LCase(strArray(i + 1)) Then
                strWert = strArray(i)
                strArray(i) = strArray(i + 1)
                strArray(i + 1) = strWert
            End If
        Next i
    Next z

    BubbleSort = strArray
End Function
```